# regex replace part of match (in group)

Tags: python, regex

The input are many files with little differences, eg. h3 can be h2, or can be two 
 at ending - so want to use (ver1|ver2|ver3), but want to replace only part of match.

regex (which doesn't work)

```
filedata = re.sub(r"""
  \uF0B7<br/>\n                          # Ě<br/> this means punctation mark
  (?P<txt>.*?)                           # this is text
  (?P<end>(?:<br/>)\n|\n<h)              # this is versions of endings
""",'\n<li>\g<txt></li>\g<end>',filedata, flags=re.S|re.VERBOSE)
```

input:

```
(...)
\uF0B7<br/>
Something1<br/>
\uF0B7<br/>
Something2<br/>
\uF0B7<br/>
Something3
<h3>Next Topic
(...)
```

unfortunately - `(?:<br/>)` doesn't work - `<br/>` is in `\g<end>`

result:

```
  (...)
  <li>Something1</li><br/>
  <li>Something2</li><br/>
  <li>Something3</li>
  <h3>Next Topic
  (...)
```

expected result:

```
  (...)
  <li>Something1</li>
  <li>Something2</li>
  <li>Something3</li>
  <h3>Next Topic
  (...)
```

(I know, that `<li>` requires `<ul>` or `<dl>`, but this is in other regex)

Comment: Wait a minute.  I've been told that you [shouldn't use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5827958).

Comment: Have to, because the source isn't html - i'm creating html from formated string - <br/> in source is from previous step